# Deleting old output files to avoid any errors while re-running the R codes

Tags: r, file, debugging

I was using this package called `SNPRelate`. This package uses `plinkhapmap.bed`, `plinkhapmap.fam` and `plinkhapmap.bim` files that can be downloded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4c3n1snoirjyc1u/AAD1lfMQsbj4uzlNokkGZFqpa?dl=0). My problem is: when I run the code below, it creates `test1.gds` file and when I delete the `test1.gds` file and want to re-run the code it generates this error `Error in createfn.gds(out.gdsfn) : 
  The file 'mypath/Dropbox/Public/SNPRelate/test2.gds' has been created or opened.`

When I change the file name `test1.gds` to `test2.gds` or some new name for output file, I don't get this error. How do I close this file completely so I can re-run the code and get the output file (keeping the same file name) again?

```
    library("SNPRelate")
    bed.fn <- "plinkhapmap.bed"
    fam.fn <- "plinkhapmap.fam"
    bim.fn <- "plinkhapmap.bim"

    snpgdsBED2GDS(bed.fn, fam.fn, bim.fn, "test1.gds")
    snpgdsSummary("test1.gds")
    genofile <- snpgdsOpen("test1.gds")
    snpset <- snpgdsLDpruning(genofile, ld.threshold=0.2)
    snpset.id <- unlist(snpset)
```

Comment: Perhaps try running `closeAllConnections()` before running the code.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Still getting the same error.

Comment: You might want to pinpoint where the error occurs and handle the connection on exit. Notice how [this is handled in `snpgdsBED2GDS`](https://github.com/zhengxwen/SNPRelate/blob/master/R/Conversion.R#L434).